# Get all titles of area's using html dom parser

Tags: php, html, dom, domparser

Trying to get all the title="" vales of an area's but its only picking the the main title of the page.
Sample area html:

```
<area shape="poly" title="Orkney" href="orkney" coords="" />
```

The page has lots of these and i'm trying to get all the title names
My PHP:

```
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname) {
    // Create DOM from string
    $html = str_get_html($string);

    $titles = array();
    // Find all tags 
    foreach($html->find($tagname) as $element) {
        $titles[] = $element->plaintext;
    }

    return $titles;
}


print_r(getTextBetweenTags($url, 'title'));
```

All i get is the title of the page, is this the correct way, or can it not be done, thanks for any help :)

Comment: can you post the value of $url?

Answer (score 0):

call the method like this:

```
print_r(getTextBetweenTags($url, 'area'));
```

since you're searching for area tags. The title is an argument. [See this documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) for an idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for `<area>` elements and return their `title` attribute

```
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname) {
    // Create DOM from string
    $html = str_get_html($string);
    $titles = array();
    // Find all tags 
    foreach($html->find($tagname) as $element) {
        $titles[] = $element->title;
    }
    return $titles;
}

print_r(getTextBetweenTags($url, 'area'));
```

And if you using the $url for the paramenter, shouldn't you be using `file_get_html()` instead of `str_get_html()`?

Comment: I tired this but still returns blank array :(

Comment: @user1977434 are you using the url as the parameter? change `str_get_html` to `file_get_html`